# Is there a way to create different repository based on a condition in the same task in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to shorten the number of tasks I have in my playbook. I am creating a yum repository on Linux hosts and adding a different `baseurl` depending on the OS version.

It looks like this:

```yaml
vars:
  my_version: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution | int }}"
    
    
- name: create mcrepo yum repo
  yum_repository:
    name: mcrepo
    description: mcrepo
    baseurl: "{{ yum_repo_url }}"
    gpgcheck: no
    enabled: yes
    sslverify: no
  when: my_version is version('8.0', operator='lt')
 
  
- name: create mcrepo yum repo
  yum_repository:
    name: mcrepo
    description: mcrepo
    baseurl: "{{ yum_repo_url_8 }}"
    gpgcheck: no
    enabled: yes
    sslverify: no
  when: my_version is version('8.0', operator='ge')
```

Is there a way to combine these two tasks into just one so one of them doesn't always get skipped? On the linux hosts I have ansible 2.9 or 2.10.
I couldn't find a way to implement a case statement or something similar.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. But to provide an answer one may need to know more what are the URL's, how they are structured, what is the `operator` about, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [inline if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression) in order to get the right variable containing the yum repository URL:

```yaml
baseurl: >-
  {{ 
    yum_repo_url 
     if my_version is version('8.0', operator='lt') 
     else yum_repo_url_8
  }}
```